# Output HTML5 code with JSF 2

Tags: html, jsf-2, doctype

I'm trying to output an HTML5 compliant page but JSF produces an XML prolog. How can I prevent this?

**index.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">

</ui:composition>
```

**layout.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<f:view locale="#{userContext.locale}">
    <h:head>
        ...
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        ...
    </h:body>
</f:view>
</html>
```

**Generated output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>...
```

I'm using Mojarra 2.2.5.

Comment: i do it like you but with 2 diffs: 1) <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" in the template, and 2) without <f:view locale="#{userContext.locale}">, it produces valid html5 without <?xml ... . would you post your web.xml, maybe there is something in it causes your problem

Comment: Thank you. Your remark helped! I tried to clean the code and start with something simple again and it stopped working as soon as I added the composite component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood the problem. I simplified the above example but I was also including composite components the following way:

**index.xhtml**

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml"
...
      xmlns:myapp="http://myapp.com/jsf/core">
```

**myapp composite**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
...
```

Unfortunately, one of the composite file in `myapp` was declaring an XML prolog. For a reason I don't understand, the use of a composition declaring an XML prolog had the effect to add the XML prolog to the main file.